# Removing duplicated nodes from sorted linked list. Why is my output wrong?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Given a sorted linked list, delete all nodes that have duplicate numbers, leaving only distinct numbers from the original list.

Examples:

- Given `1->2->3->3->4->4->5->null`, return `1->2->5->null`.
- Given `1->1->1->2->3->null`, return `2->3->null`.

Problem:

- Given `1->1->1->2->3->null`, my solution below `return 3->null`

Can someone tell me why?

```
/**
 * Definition for ListNode
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param ListNode head is the head of the linked list
     * @return: ListNode head of the linked list
     */
    public static ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
        // write your code here
        if(head == null || head.next == null) return head;

        ListNode post = head.next;
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(head.val-1);  // make sure dummy node value is different from the head
        dummy.next = head;
        ListNode prev = dummy;

        while(post != null) {
            //System.out.println("prev.val = " + prev.val + ", curr.val = " + curr.val + ", post.val = " + post.val + ", prev.next.val = " + prev.next.val);   
            //System.out.println("prev.next.val = " + prev.next.val + ", curr.next.val = " + curr.next.val);            

            if(prev.next.val == curr.val && prev.next.val == post.val) {
                curr = curr.next;
                post = post.next;
            }
            else if(prev.next.val == curr.val && prev.next.val != post.val) {
                curr = curr.next;
                post = post.next;                
                prev.next = curr;
            }
            else {
                prev = prev.next;
                curr = curr.next;
                post = post.next;
            }
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: try returning head

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, the class is in the comment on top

Comment: @aimee, returns 0->1->1->2->3->null

Comment: Probably the best way to figure out why yours isn't working right is to single-step it in the debugger. That way you can examine your `prev`, `curr`, and `post` variables, and see which branches are taken. Or, you could pretend to be a computer and walk through the algorithm step-by-step with a short sample list. (What we called "desk checking" before the days of source level debuggers.)

Comment: @JimMischel, the problem I have is I have walked through on pen and paper multiple times and I think this is the scenario where I am missing some trivial things but I cannot figure out what! Debugger is great, but I am also practicing debugging problems without debugger and improving my white board bug free skill.

Comment: @JimMischel, anyway, I was printing all the node values in each loop. Still can't figure out why in the last loop, the 2 suddenly got removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing what your program does,
the `while` loop can be transformed to this more readable form:

```
while (post != null) {
    if (prev.next.val != curr.val || prev.next.val != post.val) {
        if (prev.next.val == curr.val) {
            prev.next = curr.next;
        } else {
            prev = prev.next;
        }
    }
    curr = curr.next;
    post = post.next;
}
```

This is equivalent to your actual code.
I will explain based on this version,
because I find this easier to read and reason about.

Let's observe a few things:

- In the beginning, `prev.next` points at `curr`.
  So `prev.next.val` is equal to `curr.val`.
  Also, `post` is one step ahead of `curr`.
- `curr` moves together with `post`.
  `curr` and `post` are not changed inside the `if` condition,
  and as the last step of the loop, 
  they both advance by one position forward.

Given the input 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, and the above observations:

- The outer `if` condition will be false until `post` reaches 2.
- `curr` is one step behind, so it points to the 1 that's right before 2.
- `prev` did not move, so `prev.next` still points to the first 1.
- So at this point, `prev.next.val` is equal to `curr.val` (both 1),
  but it's not equal to `post.val`, which is 2.
  So we enter the outer if.
- As `prev.next.val == curr.val`, we also enter the inner `if`,
  and set `prev.next = curr.next`.
  Remember that the last step of the loop will be advancing `curr` to `curr.next`.
  So `prev.next` will be pointing at `curr`.
- In the next iteration, we have `post` at 3, and `curr` at 2, and `prev.next` pointing at `curr`. So we enter the other `if`, and then the inner `if`, setting `prev.next` to `curr.next`, which is 3.

And this is the end. `prev` never moved, it stayed where it was, which is `dummy`. `prev.next` is pointing at 3, which we return, incorrectly.
Note that if the input was longer, for example 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
the same behavior will continue,
`prev.next` following `curr`,
and the implementation would incorrectly return `6 -> null`.
The algorithm is broken.

---

Consider this alternative algorithm:

1. Create a dummy node, pointing to `head` as next (as you already did)
2. Set the current node to dummy
3. While the next node exists, and the next-next node exists

   - Compare `next.val` and `next.next.val`
   - If not equal, then advance the current node
   - If equal, then:

     - Save a copy of `next.val`
     - Skip `next` and `next.next` (set next to `next.next.next`)
     - Skip all further nodes whose value is equal to the saved `val`
4. Return `dummy.next`

Like this:

```
if (head == null) return head;

ListNode dummy = new ListNode(head.val - 1);
dummy.next = head;

ListNode node = dummy;
while (node.next != null && node.next.next != null) {
    if (node.next.val != node.next.next.val) {
        node = node.next;
    } else {
        int val = node.next.val;
        node.next = node.next.next.next;
        while (node.next != null && node.next.val == val) {
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }
    }
}

return dummy.next;
```

Comment: @JimMischel you're right, I misread the description. I fixed it now.

Comment: I agree your algorithm works. But why is my algorithm and/or implementation not working properly? That is the original question I have.

Comment: @elixir I added more explanation at the top, detailing how your algorithm breaks, before presenting the alternative algorithm that works.